# Pentaho behind nginx server

Tags: nginx, pentaho

I have a pentaho installation behind a nginx webserver.
What I'm trying to do is to redirect my / to /pentaho without success. This is my virtual host file:

```
server {          
  listen          80;
  server_name estrategia-bi.ddns.net;
  root /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/pentaho;

#  rewrite ^(.*)$  $scheme://estrategia-bi.ddns.net/pentaho/Login;

  location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
 }
}
```

I tried different approaches like:

```
 proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/pentaho/;
```

But this give me a kind of blank or partially load page.

```
rewrite ^(.*)$  $scheme://estrategia-bi.ddns.net/pentaho;
```

But this gave me a server error like the url it's not complete?

I don't know how to do it. Hope somebody can help me.

Regards!

Answer (score 3):

The issue that @markemus mentioned stems from revers-proxying https to http. The browser security will block mixed content from loading.
I was finally able to get this to work using the following configuration. I this configuration includes https and certificates on port 443, but it would work as easily with port 80 and http or redirect from 80 to 443 in NGINX.

NGINX:

```
server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name my.exampledomain.com;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/certificate
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key

    location /pentaho/ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/pentaho/;
    }   
}
```

Modify pentaho-server/tomcat/conf/server.xml to match entry:

```
<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
        connectionTimeout="20000"
        redirectPort="8443" 
        proxyName="my.exampledomain.com"
        proxyPort="443"
        scheme="https"
 />
```

Modify pentaho-server/pentaho-solutions/system/server.properties to match entry:

```
fully-qualified-server-url=https://my.exampledomain.com/pentaho/
```

Make sure you restart pentaho server and nginx

Answer (score 1):

This rewrite worked for us:

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name estrategia-bi.ddns.net;
    root /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/pentaho;
    rewrite ^/$ /pentaho/ permanent;
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:8080/;
    }
}
```

We never found a way to completely redirect all internal urls- that stuff you've got in location won't do it, and nothing else we tried worked either. Pentaho seems to just ignore headers.

But this rewrite will get you to the login page. After logging in, you will be redirected to http://localhost:8080/pentaho/ for some reason. Reload the main page and you should be logged in, after which everything should work normally.